# Cyclic Encoding vs One hot encoding for random forest?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

My task involves determining the number of accidents that could occur across various time periods on a specific route. Initially for a list of locations on a route, I determine if an accident will occur and later sum up the number of accidents for the route. Now, I've used day of the year, weekday and hour as the features along with weather attributes. I also used DBSCAN clustering to cluster locations into hotspots.
I would expect to see peaks in the afternoon hours (13-15) or early morning hours (7-10) as it was also observed in the training data as well.
But unfortunately, I get peak accident count at 23 hr. I used cyclic encoding to check if the problem could be addressed by encoding time etc. but doesn't seem to work and performs worse.

```
modelFeatures['hour_sin'] = modelFeatures.apply(lambda row: math.sin(2 * math.pi * row['Hour']/24.0),axis=1)
modelFeatures['hour_cos'] = modelFeatures.apply(lambda row: math.cos(2 * math.pi * row['Hour']/24.0),axis=1)
modelFeatures['weekday_sin'] = modelFeatures.apply(lambda row: math.sin(2 * math.pi * row['Weekday']/7.0),axis=1)
modelFeatures['weekday_cos'] = modelFeatures.apply(lambda row: math.cos(2 * math.pi * row['Weekday']/7.0),axis=1)
modelFeatures['dayOfYear_sin'] = modelFeatures.apply(lambda row: math.sin(2 * math.pi * row['DayOfYear']/366.0),axis=1)
modelFeatures['dayOfYear_cos'] = modelFeatures.apply(lambda row: math.cos(2 * math.pi * row['DayOfYear']/366.0),axis=1)
```

Is it a good option to use cyclic encoding for random forest, as sin and cos data for the same time will be treated differently.
Is it feasible to use one hot encoding for date-time attributes or what could be the reason that there are peaks only at 23hrs?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to ask similar question at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) instead.

I do not understand all the details from your task, but in general, RFs do not need this (quote from [Cyclical features encoding, it’s about time!](https://towardsdatascience.com/cyclical-features-encoding-its-about-time-ce23581845ca)):

> Decision trees based algorithms (Random Forest, Gradient Boosted Trees, XGBoost) build their split rules according to one feature at a time. This means that they will fail to process these two features simultaneously whereas the cos/sin values are expected to be considered as one single coordinates system.

You can find some [examples](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-hot-encoding-is-making-your-tree-based-ensembles-worse-heres-why-d64b282b5769) where one hot encoding makes your based tree algorithm worse.

If you are looking for more details about approaches to time encoding, I would recommend [this blob post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/three-approaches-to-encoding-time-information-as-features-for-ml-models/).